# $(window).on("load") gets executed before $(document).ready. Shouldn't ready be executed first?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var h = $("#im").height();
            alert("Hello from ready. Height is " + h);
        });
        $(window).on("load", function(){
            var h = $("#im").height();
            alert("Hello from load. Height is " + h);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="" id="msg"></p>
    <p class="" id="msg2"></p>
    <img id="im" src="flower.jpg" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

1) The above is my code. When I run this in Chrome 64 (64 bit). The window.load portion gets executed before document.ready.

2) Secondly, based what I have read on these forums and elsewhere on the net, I should not be able to get the image height from document.ready, and yet, it works and I get the same height from both the functions.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there something wrong with being able to get the image height? I can't imagine how this can possibly count as an error. Also, clear your cache. The browser might be able to tell image properties of cached images straight-away. I'm sure that *"`load` happens before all images have finished loading"* does not mean *"when `load` happens, we guarantee that **no** images have finished loading"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's `ready` event is first processed by its `Deferred` implementation, which internally uses [`setTimeout`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3d732cca6b5076a9d13eee98e2b075b37384cd91/src/deferred.js#L230) (probably to allow [`$.holdReady`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/) to function). It's essentially this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Your `ready` callback
    }, 0);
});
```

Using `setTimeout(..., 0)` can delay the execution of your callback enough to allow the `load` event to run its callback first if your page is simple enough. I tested it on Chrome 64.0.3282.186 and the jQuery `ready` event fired before `load` only about 10% of the time.

If you use `document.addEventListener` directly, your code works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

Get image info after window is loaded or add an eventListener to the image.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {/*Do Stuff*/}
```

**or**

```
$('#image').on('load', function() {/*Do Stuff*/}
```

Here is the solution of your question on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlocorradini/pen/MQZQJx).

## Solution 2

True, when document is ready only the structure is loaded, instead, window is loaded all components including images and more is ready and loaded.

More: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Hope this helps.